# setup vpn for remote team to use

Tags: router, vpn

I just have my laptop and router

I don't have much access to the router either to change settings. How can I set up a VPN for a remote team to use

where basically it works much like a proxy, they use their internet but it connects through mine

Comment: assuming your router does NAT/PAT, and you don't have much access to the router,  your choices are limited. since most VPNs either involve terminating on teh router or Port forwarding into the VPN host.  You could probably try something with Reverse SSH tunnnels or the like.  BUt what you not have much access to the router? Who does?

Comment: If you just want your teammates to have access to your files you can use either TeamViewer (full control of pc) or you can use hamachi which will create a vpn between you and your teammates.